# Can't access `this` in Vue 3 methods with regular OR arrow functions

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm not able to reference my data fields in my Vue 3 methods because of some misunderstanding in syntax and scope.

I'm using Typescript. I know this question has been asked to death but I can't for the life of me find out how to make the arrow functions of TS work to give me access to the Vue context as `this`

My code is simple:

```
  export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    userLogin() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password) //ERROR! Undefined
        .then((user: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
          //do stuff
        })
        .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
          //do other stuff
        });
    }
```

The guide here calls out this issue by saying:

> An arrow function uses what is called lexical scoping. We'll get into this more in a bit, but it >basically means that the arrow function takes this from it's context.
>
> If you try to access this from inside of an arrow function that's on a Vue component, you'll get an >error because this doesn't exist!

but it falls frustratingly short of actually providing an example fix. What do I do to access those data variables in my methods? I've tried the following and none of them work:

```
userLogin() {
      const self = this
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(self.email, self.password)
...

userLogin = () => {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
...
```

Comment: Your first syntax looks correct to me... What does `this` come up as if you `console.log(this)` inside `userLogin`?

Comment: Yeah, looks fine to me. Consider the context where you're calling the `userLogin()` function from. For example, if you don't have something like `v-on:click="userLogin"`, check that the function isn't being called outside of Vue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using TypeScript to define a component, always use

```js
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
...
```

That should solve the problem.

If it doesn't, then try this:

```js
 methods: {
    userLogin() {
         const email = this.email;
         const password = this.password;
         firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
          //do stuff
        })
        .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
          //do other stuff
        });
    }
```

Comment: Using `defineComponent` worked like a charm. Is this making `this` be the vue context to within all the Vue SFC methods/objects it wraps?

Comment: Indeed, according to the documentation `To let TypeScript properly infer types inside Vue component options, you need to define components with defineComponent global method` ref: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecomponent